# CodeIgniter Transaction not working properly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this function in my model that is supposed to run two queries in a transaction, but the update query is not working.

```
public function delete($id = null) 
{
    if($id) {
        $delete = "DELETE FROM borrowed_books 
        WHERE id = '$id'; ";

        $mod="UPDATE `books` b
              INNER JOIN `borrowed_books` a
              SET b.nr_copies=b.nr_copies+1
              WHERE b.id_book=a.id_book AND a.id = '$id'; ";

        $this->db->trans_start();
        $this->db->query($delete);
        $this->db->query($mod);
        $this->db->trans_complete();
        if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }   

}
```

Comment: In addition to @Brian Gottier's answer I would suggest removing the 'DELETE' part completely and just using 'UPDATE'.  Additionally use the CI notation: e.g. `$this->db->where('id', $id); $this->db->update('books', array('due-date' => 'a date')); ` You also seem to have a redundant id `id_book`, why not have just `id`?  Have an additional field on your record called `due-date` or something and if that is null it hasn't been borrowed... KISS principle

Comment: @eli if you getting some error then only `trans_status()` through error but in `update` query there is not error so i will delete record n update records if conditions matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quickfix might be executing the update before deleting;

```
public function delete($id = null)
{
    if ($id) {
        $delete = "DELETE FROM borrowed_books 
        WHERE id = '$id'; ";

        $mod="UPDATE `books` b
              INNER JOIN `borrowed_books` a
              SET b.nr_copies=b.nr_copies+1
              WHERE b.id_book=a.id_book AND a.id = '$id'; ";

        $this->db->trans_start();
        // execute the update
        $this->db->query($mod);
        // then delete
        $this->db->query($delete);
        $this->db->trans_complete();
        if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }   
}
```

The update query condition; it is looking for data which is not existent because you deleted it. So if you do the update (then your query finds result assuming that the condition is correct), it will update..

Comment: "Quick fix" ... because updating something your going to delete is the right thing to do. And you've got the accepted answer ... 6 hours after I told him what was wrong. This is no answer, this is just leading somebody down the road of bad coding.

Answer (score 2):

It would be impossible to update something that isn't there. In the first query, your delete query, you delete from the borrowed_books `WHERE id = '$id'`, but then right after that you are trying to update the very borrowed_books record(s) with the same ID, `and a.id = '$id'`. It won't update because there is nothing to update.

To make clear, in the second query, `a.id` is referring to the id of the borrowed_books table, yet in the delete query (the first query), you just deleted that very same borrowed_books record, so there is nothing to join.

Answer (score 0):

`INNER JOIN` can't find a data out that you already deleted in first step of your transaction, you need query the specific `borrowed_books` data and save it in a variable before you delete it. By the way I never saw people use UPDATE like this `UPDATE .... INNER JOIN`in sql, and it make your code so confused, I change your code a little, I think it is more understandable.

```
public function delete($id = null)
{
    if ($id) {
        $borrowedBook = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM borrowed_books WHERE id=' . $id);

        $delete = "DELETE FROM borrowed_books 
        WHERE id = '$id'; ";


        $mod = "UPDATE books SET nr_copies = nr_copies + 1 WHERE id_book = " . $borrowedBook->id_book;

        $this->db->trans_start();
        // execute the update
        $this->db->query($mod);
        // then delete
        $this->db->query($delete);
        $this->db->trans_complete();
        if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }   
}
```